# Interactive two panels diff for *nix console?

Tags: linux, unix, graphical-user-interface, diff

Could you please advise me about interactive two panels diff tool, something like http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/, but for *nix console/ncurses 
or maybe somebody knows how DiffMerge can be run over SSH connection seamlessly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim has vimdiff mode which is quite good. It obviously works in console mode too.

It give you color highlighting of differences and the possibility to edit the diffed files efficiently. Vim is also installable or even installed on most *nix system these days...

It is better if you already know Vim though...

Comment: Plus you can use `]c` `[c` to navigate to the differences and `dp` `do` to put or obtain them from the other pane

Answer (score 2):

meld is a good but graphical diff tool. But you can use it over ssh X forward or with sshfs.

Comment: Still requires the whole stack of X libraries to be installed…